# How do I keep on executing this code until the last element comes "4" in the output list?

Tags: python, list

When I execute the code below, I'm getting

`[0,0,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,7]`

However, I expect this:

`[0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4]`

I expect that output because `print` should only happen until the last element of list (tails[-1]) is equal to 4.

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed()
tails = [0]
for x in range(10):
    coin = np.random.randint(0, 2)
    tails.append(tails[x] + coin)
    if tails[-1] == 4:
        print(tails)
```

Comment: Why are you appending `tails[x] + coin` if you don't want that? Also, You say, "last element comes 4", and then you write `tails[-1] == 7` ? What???

Comment: Your question is not completely clear. You print when checking for 7 and in the text you state that you don't want to print when its 7

Comment: What is the logic behind the expected output? What makes numbers increase from 0 to 4?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh The logic behind this is im trying to print the number of occurance of tails by randomly assigning 0 or 1 `np.random.randint(0, 2)` and trying to record the random walk.

Comment: clean up the code, keep a variable that counts how many tails were seen so far. Worry about "recording the random walk" afterwards. Write something simple that displays whether you got heads or tails on each round first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `break` keyword after printing last element in `tails` if it is **`4`**.

```
if tails[-1] == 4:
    print(tails)
    break
```

and then may be try exiting the script using `sys.exit()`.

Comment: Actually if tails[-1]==4 then it prints. Else , not.
But what i want is, if the `if` condition fails, it should go again and execute in the for loop

Answer (score 0):

This was the code which I was expecting:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed()
tails = [0]
def loop():
    for x in range(10):
        coin = np.random.randint(0, 2)
        tails.append(tails[x] + coin)
    return tails
while True:
    loop()
    if tails[-1] == 4:
        print(str(tails)+' - !! success !!')
        break
    else :
        x = 1
        for i in range(10):
            for i in range(1, x + 1):
                b = tails.pop(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your code (added break)

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed()
tails = [0]
for x in range(10):
    coin = np.random.randint(0, 2)
    tails.append(tails[x] + coin)
    if tails[-1] == 4:
        print(tails)
        break            # breaks out the loop
```